# How to make gb2312 show normally in localhost?

Tags: html, character-encoding, docsify

I have a lot of htmls encoded in gb2312 and they look good when I open them directly in browser. But now I use docsify to deploy them in server, words become messy code in localhost. Is there a way to make the words show normally?[image]

Comment: Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)…

Comment: @JosefZ Yes, I used an application to transform all the gb2312 into utf8 and it worked.